# Postfix - NDR messages immediately when sent to a bad domain

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, ndr

We have a service that we offer to one of our clients that sends statements to their clients.  Unfortunately, our customer's validation of email addresses isn't always the best, so when they submit a batch to us to send we usually see a lot of emails that fail to send due to misspellings of common domains (ex. gnail.com, htmail.com, etc.).  We collect the bounce backs to give to our client to fix their email list, but until that bounce back/NDR occurs, these messages remain in our postfix mailq until they reach the queue expiry time.  Retrying to send again and again.

Is there any good way to have postfix send an NDR for these messages immediately on the first failure instead of trying again and again?  We only want this to happen to bad domains though, sometimes, we see messages deferred due to greylisting, and they go out on the second attempt.

I have tried out my Google-foo, but it seems to be failing me in this task...

Comment: Perhaps you could validate the domain names before ever trying to send any mail?

Comment: Do you have a good way to know which failures you want to treat this way? Any type of failure for any delivery to any recipient? Your examples are valid domains that exist (but likely not the intended domains), which is probably part of why you don't immediately get a permanent failure.

Comment: @Håkan Lindqvist what you are saying is correct. It seems that when looking at the domains they can be seen to be incorrect, but when doing a DNS check, there are A records in place for them.  Is there any way in postfix to have a blacklist of domains that should just be NDRed immediately when someone attempts to send to them?  Maybe something like smtpd_recipient_restrictions, that would send an custom NDR that they invalid domain specified?  Not sure if postfix supports that much customization for bounces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by rejecting completely invalid mail by adding `reject_non_fqdn_recipient` and `reject_unknown_recipient_domain` to appropriate restriction table.

Postfix can additionally `REJECT` messages via `check_recipient_mx_access` and `check_recipient_access`, but how you generate an appropriate lookup depends on your acceptable level of error (rejecting non-typos / non-rejecting typos).

**Ideally, never deliver mail to a recipient domain with small [*Levensthein distance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to a much more popular recipient domain.** The larger the volume difference between the designated recipient and a similar-sounding target, the less likely the recipient is the intended one (*one does not simply operate a large email service that spells *almost* like `gmail.com`*).

What is much simpler and worked for me was a `pcre` table that had the most commonly mistyped domain hardcoded like:

```
# reject recipient MX table
typosquatter.example        REJECT
shady-data-broker.example   REJECT

# reject recipient domain table
# skip the correct one
example.com            DUNNO
# broadly reject all minor permutations
..ample.com            REJECT
ex..ple.com            REJECT
exa..le.com            REJECT
# ...
example.co             REJECT
```

I kept false positives at an acceptable level by never matching both TLD change and permutations at once - all the big recipients do not sound too similar to other legitimate businesses anyway.
Why was this sufficient for me, even though I did not match all permutations? Because 90% of typos are in the same group of 5% possible permutations, so it catched *most* typos.

If you have logs of at least a few months, you can probably get a pretty good start by just grepping for queue timeouts from connection timeouts, removing false positives by hand and completing the list like I did above.